# Code calculates the sum of a range of rows but the average row calculation then included the sum row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite inexperienced with VBA 
My code calculates the sum of a range of rows (dynamic) and places these values 2 rows beneath the last row. Beneath that I want the average values. The verage calculation  is including the sum row and is therefore doubling all the average values

```
Dim r As Range, j As Long, k As Long
j = Sheets(2).Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column


'This adds up the totals on the Sorted1 sheet
For k = 9 To j
Set r = Sheets(2).Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, k), Sheets(2).Cells(1, k).End(xlDown))
r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
Next k


Else

MsgBox ("There is no data at column D")
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myColumn As Range
Dim myDataSet As Range
Dim myAvg As Double
Dim LastRow as long


Set mySheet = ActiveSheet
For Each myColumn In mySheet.Range("I:Q").Columns
lastRow = mySheet.Cells(mySheet.Rows.Count, myColumn.Column).End(xlUp).row
myAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(myColumn.Rows(1).Resize(lastRow, 1))
myColumn.Rows(lastRow).Offset(1, 0).Value = myAvg
Next
```

I'm trying to find a way of excluding the Sum row from being a part of the average row calculations.

End Sub

Comment: `r.End(xlDown).Offset(3, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Average(r)`, after `r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)`?

Comment: That worked brilliantly I've now got all the averages under all the totals I don't need two of the average results returned (column M and column o).Is there a way to exclude them?

Comment: Add an `If`: `If k <> 13 And k <> 15 Then`.